# GuzzleHttp 6 choose local public ip to send request

Tags: guzzle

I use GuzzleHttp to send request to an external API. This API implements a throttling to limit requests to a maximum per second per distant IP.
I will built a local queuing component but I want to speed up requests and use some of my public IPs to load-balance or use them successively.

I'm looking for a solution to create GuzzleHttp client and force it to use one of my local public IP or another.

On a general PHP basis, I found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/667485/352259) a way to bind a socket in a stream context, using file_get_contents

I browsed GuzzleHttp and PSR-7 code and found that it uses StreamInterface that may be wrapped and may be use a stream context in a similar way.

But I can't find a way to do so.
Can you give me an example how to implement that ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it'll help but with curl you can do it like this:

```
curl --interface zz.zz.zz.zz http://example.com/
```

I also need to bind Guzzle to one of my IP addresses but didn't find the solution yet...

Update:
I have found a hint how to do it with Http package in Laravel (I didn't test it yet). Maybe this will be of some help.

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
    'curl' => [CURLOPT_INTERFACE => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'],
])->get('http://example.com/users');
```